# Showing an error .SplashActivity not assignable to Android.App.Activity

Tags: android

*I am trying to add a splash screen to my app to make it look better.*
I am getting an error that .SplashActivity not assignable to android.app.acticity

```
<application

    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true">
<activity
    android:name=".SplashActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
    <activity
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar"
     android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: post your splashcreen code

Comment: probably your SplashActivity is just a java class not activity. Please recheck.

Comment: I faced same problem..It was showing error in `Manifest.xml`, but when I run the code, it worked without any runtime errors...

Comment: if error persists, try to downgrade dependancy in `build.gradle` for `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'`...

Answer (score 1):

Extendeded `AppCompatActivity` to
public class SplashActivity.

My code was like.

```
public class SplashActivity  {

}
```

changed it to

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

}
```